# Adding collection_check_boxes method to add tags using ActsAsTaggableOn gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox, acts-as-taggable-on

I am using ActsAsTaggableOn gem and want to select multiple tags from the tag list. So I tried to select multiple tags using dropdown. The code is as follows:

```
    = form_for(@post) do |f|
      - if @post.errors.any?
      #error_explanation
        %h2
          = pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error")
          prohibited this post from being saved:
        %ul
          - @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
            %li= msg
      .field
        = f.label :title
        %br/
        = f.text_field :title
      .field
        = f.label :body
        %br/
        = f.cktext_area :body, :class => 'ckeditor'
      .field
        = f.label :tag_list
        %br/
        = f.collection_select :tag_list, ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all, :id, :name, :prompt => "--- Select Tags ---", {:multiple => true}
      .actions
        = f.submit
```

But somehow I was able to select only single tag and not multiple. So I am now using checkbox for multiple selection of tags. The modified line in code looks like following:

```
    = f.collection_check_boxes :tag_list, ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all, :id, :name
```

Now the output looks like,

```
Tag list
[#", label="Check">, #", label="Invitation">, #", label="Payment">, #", label="Complain">, #", label="Maintenance">, #", label="Meeting">]
```

I am not sure what is the problem. I am new to ruby and it might have a simple solution to problem which I am not able to figure out. Please help me as I have Googled for a day and tried all changes but still stuck with this problem.

**Edit**

When `raw` removed, it renders as:

```
Tag list
[#<struct MetaSearch::Check box="<input id=\"post_tag_list_1\" name=\"post[tag_list][]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"1\" />", label="<label for=\"post_tag_list_1\">Check</label>">, #<struct MetaSearch::Check box="<input id=\"post_tag_list_2\" name=\"post[tag_list][]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"2\" />", label="<label for=\"post_tag_list_2\">Invitation</label>">, #<struct MetaSearch::Check box="<input id=\"post_tag_list_3\" name=\"post[tag_list][]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"3\" />", label="<label for=\"post_tag_list_3\">Payment</label>">, #<struct MetaSearch::Check box="<input id=\"post_tag_list_4\" name=\"post[tag_list][]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"4\" />", label="<label for=\"post_tag_list_4\">Complain</label>">, #<struct MetaSearch::Check box="<input id=\"post_tag_list_5\" name=\"post[tag_list][]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"5\" />", label="<label for=\"post_tag_list_5\">Maintenance</label>">, #<struct MetaSearch::Check box="<input id=\"post_tag_list_6\" name=\"post[tag_list][]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"6\" />", label="<label for=\"post_tag_list_6\">Meeting</label>">]
```

Comment: Don't use `raw` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for select multiple tags http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ - Multi-Value Select Boxes